# AEM Workflow Thumbnails

Tags: aem

I am trying to find a way to extract thumbnails from images inside an AEM workflow. The class `FFMpegThumbnailProcess`, inside `cq-dam-video-5.8.2.jar`, does it for video.

Is there a class that does it for images?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `DAM Update Assset` workflow in your workflow console, `localhost:<port>/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html`.

It should have a process step named `Thumbnail creation`. You can check what class that step uses, in my AEM 6.0 instance is `com.day.cq.dam.core.process.CreateThumbnailProcess`.